# Sort by key in Excel connected to SSAS OLAP cube

Tags: excel, ssas, olap

I searched the Internet and StackOverflow and was not able to find an answer to this issue.  I created an OLAP cube via SSAS with a date dimension.  One of the attributes of the dimension is *Activity Calendar Month*.  The `NameColumn` value is formatted like "January 2015", "February 2015", etc.

The `KeyColumns` is set as a DATE value type for the first of the month, for each month.  Example, `NameColumn` value "January 2015" = `KeyColumns` value "1/1/2015", "February 2015" = "2/1/2015", etc.

The `ValueColumn` is also set to first of the month date (i.e. '1/1/2015') in case Excel was using that for sorting.

When I view the *Calendar Month* dimension in an Excel 2013 workbook, it initially loads with the correct sorting.  Below is a sample:

```
January 2015
February 2015
March 2015
April 2015
May 2015
June 2015
July 2015
August 2015
September 2015
```

However, I want to be able to right-click  on the field in Excel and select *Sort > Sort Z to A* and sort the months descending. When I currently do this, I get back:

```
September 2015
May 2015
March 2015
June 2015
July 2015
January 2015
February 2015
August 2015
April 2015
```

To me, it appears the Excel will only sort based on the alphanumeric value set in the dimension's `NameColumn`.  Also, if I drop the years from the month values (i.e. "January" instead of "January 2015"), Excel seems to understand that it is a month and sorts the months correctly.

## Screen Shot of Dimension Settings

[image: Activity Calendar Month properties]

## Questions

- Does Excel have the capability to sort on values outside of `NameColumn`, such as `KeyColumns` or `ValueColumn`, **where** the `NameColumn` does not use standard month names (i.e. "January", "February", etc.)?
- If yes, then what might I be missing in the SSAS dimension setup to make this work?

Comment: Did check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166763.aspx)? You should order `Calendar Month` by `Month Number Of Year `

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, yes, I did see that link and tried that.  I have tried to set the separate attribute member as a integer (i.e. 1-12) and a date (1/1/2015) for each month.  They do sort fine in the *Browser*  tab of the dimension in Visual Studio, and again, are initially sorted correctly in Excel.  I still am unable to change the sort order in Excel as it sorts the months alphanumerically by the name, not respecting the sort setting for the dimension.

Comment: @ShayneEphraim, did you get a way to sort in excel based on dimension key field and not name field, as it usually does?

Answer (score 3):

Can you read the last paragraph here:
https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Show%20Property%20as%20Caption&referringTitle=Home

> One advantage of the built-in "Show Properties In Report" feature is that the member properties come through into Excel with their proper datatypes. So a member property of datetime datatype comes across as such and can be formatted using Excel formatting. And numeric member properties come across as such and can be formatted in Excel. However, when you use any member property as a caption using the "Show Property as Caption" OLAP PivotTable Extensions feature, the caption comes across as a string and cannot be formatted in Excel, unfortunately.

It talks about formatting in Excel but I believe sorting in Excel applies too.

So... Add a new member property of your Activity Calendar Month attribute with the same date key (first of the month) then add that member property to the PivotTable and try to sort by it. If you can, great. If not then install that OLAP PivotTable Extensions add-in and use Show Property As Caption then sort. Make sense?

P.S. Thanks for the very well written question!

Comment: Although this is a good workaround, it would be fine if I were the only user of the cube.  The issue is that there are other end users who may not be able to understand how the *OLAP PivotTable Extensions* works, let alone be able to install this on their systems.  

I voted this up since it was a good suggestion, but still looking for a solution to sort months descending in Excel that include the year (i.e. January 2015).  Dropping the year does sort fine.  I am thinking that question may not have a solution.